# Web Server Scripting Hack to Maintain State and Keep a Domain Cookieless

Tags: php, apache-2.2, lamp, cname-record, cookieless

I am looking for a solution on a LAMP server to keep a site cookieless such as "example.com", where static content is served from "static.example.com", and with rules in place to rewrite requests for "www.example.com" to "example.com". I am really hoping to avoid setting up a cookieless domain for the static content due to an unanswered SEO concern with regards to CNAMEing to a CDN. Is there a way, (or safe hack), that can be implemented where a second domain such as "www.example2.com" is CNAMEd, aliased, or otherwise used with "example.com" to somehow trick a php application into maintaining state with a cookie dropped on "www.example2.com" therefore keeping all of "example.com" cookieless?

If such a solution is feasible, what implications would exists with regards to SSL and cross-browser compatibility other than requiring users to accept cookies from 3rd party domains and possibly needing an additional SSL to keep the cookie secure?

Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can host your static content anywhere. I recommend setting up a CNAME to your static assets so you can have a nice domain like static.sample.com to reference in your code. Regarding www.example.com and example.com, you should point example.com to your IP and www.example.com is simply a CNAME that points to example.com.

Regarding cookies, I'm not sure I follow your question, but you can set cookies on example.com that will show on any variation of that domain (app1.example.com, static.example.com www.example.com)

Simply prepend the domain name with a period to have the cookie apply to all subdomains: ".example.com"

Comment: thanks for the reply Erik. what i am aiming for is to keep the cookie valid on example.com only and none of it's subdomains. it's a maximizing performance issue where cookies are currently dropping with every static asset.

Comment: You should be able to simply set the cookie without the initial period then. 

However, this will lock it to that domain. You'll need to do a URL re-write to return a 301 and redirect traffic from www.example.com to example.com or vice-versa.

You can see the three lines you'll need to add to your .htaccess file here, it maps www.af-design.com to af-design.com:
http://af-design.com/blog/2008/11/12/301-redirects-in-apache/